# Create a custom field with my plugin data

Tags: plugin-development, categories, custom-fieldtype, entries-field

I want to create a field like categories but using my plugin data.

I need to be able to select one element in entry page to get all the elements from my plugin group base on that selection.

do i go with a custom field type or there is another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions is a bit short on details but from what you've posted, it sounds like a [custom field type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/field-types) is what you're looking for.